# Find the differential equation of $y=e^{-x}+ax+b$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Find the differential equation of $$y=e^{-x}+ax+b$$   where $a,b$ are arbitrary constants.

I differentiated both sides first, and got $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-e^{-x}+a.$$

Making substitution for value of $a$ in the original equation and differentiating again, I got $$x\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2e^{-x}-xe^{-x}.$$

So, the differential equation turns out to be $$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\dfrac{e^{-x}(2-x)}{x}.$$

Have I made any mistake here? My teacher struck the whole thing out and gave me a $0$ here. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by THE differential equation?

Comment: This question makes no sense as it stands. There are infinitely many ODEs we could construct from the original function. So, as Zachary pointed out, what do you mean by _the_ differential equation?

Comment: @ZacharySelk I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: No, it still doesn't make any sense

Comment: I don't know how you got the third line but it is wrong since $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=e^{-x}$$

Comment: I just want to say that I am a high school student and whatever you are saying does not make any sense to me. If it would be possible for you to understand my situation, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you saw this in the context of linear second order differential equations with constant coefficients? Then in the form of the solution, you recognize what should be the solution of the homogeneous part (in blue) and a particular solution (in red):
$$y=\color{red}{e^{-x}}+\color{blue}{ax+b}$$
Now for the homogeneous part, you need a double zero root to the characteristic equation so this is clearly the solution to:
$$y''=0$$
To get $e^{-x}$ as a particular solution, the inhomogeneous part of the differential equation (the "right-hand side") will be of the form $Ae^{-x}$ and you can verify (easily) that $A=1$ does the trick, so:
$$y''=e^{-x} \tag{$\square$}$$
has $y=\color{red}{e^{-x}}+\color{blue}{ax+b}$ as general solution.

---

Addition after comment.

> $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-e^{-x}+a. \tag{$*$}$$
>
> Making substitution for value of $a$ in the original equation and differentiating again, I got $$x\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2e^{-x}-xe^{-x}.$$

If you substituted $(*)$ in the original solution, where did the $b$ go? Why not differentiate $(*)$ again, this immediately yields $(\square).$

Comment: I think you may have understood what I was trying to ask. Would you please help me, kind sir with why my approach is wrong in substituting the value of $a$ in the original equation if you have understood the problem which others did not?

Comment: @Swadhin I'm not really sure what you were doing, but I added a part to my answer.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, thank you for your time. After all this, I am not sure about all this myself. So, I guess it would be better if I asked my teacher directly.

Comment: Alright; you're welcome and good luck with that!